# Agregar mas de una clase en Module SCSS en React

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks, sass, scss

Hola estoy trabajando en React con funciones y quisiera agregar 3 clases SCSS, la cual una de esas tres clases es opcional (soloVer) y otra ya es fija como la clase Pill

Las clases son PILL, MEDIO, PEQUEÑO, soloVer

A continuación les muestro el código SCSS

```
.pill{
    display: inline-block;
    border: 1px solid map-get($coloresGrises, grisOscuro);
    color: map-get($coloresGrises, grisOscuro);
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;

    .medio{
        font-size: 0.875rem;
        line-height: 1.5rem;

        border-radius: 0.25rem;
        padding: 88px 12px;

        &:active{
            border: 1px solid map-get($coloresBrand, primario800);
            color: map-get($coloresBrand, primario800);
        }

        &:disabled{
            border: none;
            color: map-get($coloresGrises, gris);
        }

        .soloVer{
            border: 1px solid map-get($coloresGrises, grisOscuro);
            color: map-get($coloresGrises, grisOscuro);
        }
    }

    .pequeño{
        font-size: 0.75rem;
        line-height: 1.125rem;

        border-radius: 0.25rem;
        padding: 8px 12px;

        &:active{
            border: 1px solid map-get($coloresBrand, primario800);
            color: map-get($coloresBrand, primario800);
        }

        &:disabled{
            border: none;
            color: map-get($coloresGrises, gris);
        }
    }

}
```

A continuación les muestro el código JS de React

```
import classes from './Pill.module.scss';

const Pill = ({texto, estilo, onEventoClick, disabled, estadoX, key}) => {
    return (
        <span key={key} className={[classes.pill] [classes[estilo]]} onClick={onEventoClick} disabled={disabled}>
            {texto} {estadoX && <IoClose />}
        </span>
    )
}
```

También quisiera saber si existe alguna documentación oficial de Module, para poder leer y resolver estos problemas.

Answer (score 0):

yo utilizo esta manera:

```
import classes from './Pill.module.scss';

const Pill = ({texto, estilo, onEventoClick, disabled, estadoX, key}) => {
    return (
        <span key={key} className={`${classes.pill}${classes.estilo}`} onClick={onEventoClick} disabled={disabled}>
            {texto} {estadoX && <IoClose />}
        </span>
    )
}
```

No sé si te sirva, pero hay te dejo el dato.